# character in the PDF

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
' only a test
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

If I copy the text from the PDF viewer, the following characters are in the clipboard:

```
’ only a test
```

The apostrophe is different. What can I do, that in the PDF I can grab the original input character?

Comment: `\usepackage{upquote}`

Comment: Wait until you see what happens with "ff".